# Android Instant Speech to Text voice recognition

Tags: android, accessibility, voice-recognition

I don't have much experience with Android, but was asked by a hearing-impaired friend if there is a way to essentially "stream" voice to text on a mobile device.  I've used and looked into the android built in api, but it seems that only sends the speech off for processing after the speech input is completed.  I'm looking for something that works contiguously (similar to how Dragon works with microsoft word).

Perhaps there is already an app that does this.  If not, is there a way to implement this with the current Android OS/API?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've mentioned, the speech-to-text recognition is sent to Google for processing.  This can take enormous computing power, which current devices simply can't handle (yet).  Because everything is processed server-side, you won't be able to do immediate speech recognition in real time directly on the phone.

It's possible that somebody has created a 3rd-party library to do this, but I'm not aware of any.  Even so, it would probably have some significant limitations or reduced accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  There is no way to batch process it, right? i.e. getting a 10 sec sample, sending it, and starting another 10 sec sample, etc... forever.  I suppose that could create a horrendous backup mess....

Comment: You could certainly do something like that, since your application will know when the last bit of text is done processing and you get that result.  The downside is that you'll have to stop talking every so often and wait a few seconds - the longer each voice sample is, the longer it may take to get a response.

Comment: Also, if you just keep displaying the voice input box, how would it know you're done talking and to stop showing the box? So yes, I suppose that's a valid method but it could be a frustrating experience to the end user.

Comment: Yes, Thats similar to what I thought might happen.  THanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Extra for the Recognizer Intent:

String  EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS   Optional boolean to indicate whether partial results should be returned by the recognizer as the user speaks (default is false).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS